# Network not found on 2 different laptops with 2 different Ubuntu versions

Tags: networking, network-manager

First, I apologize for being a newbie even after using Ubuntu and Linux in general for several years.

This afternoon, 08/11/2021 the network connection failed on one of my laptops [an Asus with Ubuntu 20). I believe it said the network adapter was not found.  It's and old computer so I figured it was a hardware problem.

I then went and grabbed another laptop [Lenovo with Ubuntu 18] and it displayed the same problem.

My wife's mac was connected to wifi and so was my android phone.  I was able to connect over my hotspot and am now directly plugged in to the router with an Ethernet cable.

It just seemed odd that both computers would fail at once.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

thank you
HBB

Update, Problem Solved: So after talk ing it over with my wife she suggested I get a more "mainstream" computer.  So I ordered a new chromebook.  A couple of hours later I booted up the Lenovo and it was working again. So I started up the Asus and it was working too.  I don't know what the problem was but the solution was to buy a new computer.  I have had this happen with car transmission parts and furnace parts.  Clearly the solution is to buy a new part or object.

Although I received no replies yet I appreciate that forums like this exist.

HBB

Comment: Both laptops failed when using wireless, or wired, connections? Have you rebooted the router? re: *"directly plugged in to the router with an Ethernet cable"*... from which computer... one of the laptops... or the Mac?

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 18 or 20 version what are you using?

Comment: I appreciate the help.  As I posted the problem did correct itself.

Comment: Both computers are using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.  I was wrong on what the Lenovo was using. I was able to direct connect with a cable.  As my wife's mac and iphone and my Android phone were all connecting I didn't think it was a hardware issue and did not reboot the router.  In fact I was able to connect using my phone as a hotspot.  At the end of the day when I think about it I wonder if it was a Comcast problem.